# Como resolver a exceção RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type...?

Tags: java, spring, testes-de-unidade, junit, desserialização

Estou recebendo esta exceção ao usar o `TestRestTemplate`:

> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [java.util.List<me.heenluy.travels.app.Travel>] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<me.heenluy.travels.app.Travel>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<me.heenluy.travels.app.Travel>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

**Meu código:**

```
@Autowired
TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

ResponseEntity<List<Travel>> response = restTemplate.withBasicAuth(user, password)
            .exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {});
```

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping(
        path = "travels/get/principal/list",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<List<Travel>> getListByActiveUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal AppUser user) {
    List<Travel> travels = travelService.getListByUserFromRepository(user.getEmail());
    ResponseEntity<List<Travel>> response = new ResponseEntity<>(travels, HttpStatus.OK);
            
    return response;
}
```

Por algum motivo, quando faço a requisição pelo **curl**, **Httpie** ou **RestTemplate** (sem o 'Test') funciona normalmente.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

O problema aparentemente não está na sua request, e sim no conteúdo da sua response.

> Cannot deserialize value of type java.util.ArrayList<me.heenluy.travels.app.Travel> from Object value **(token JsonToken.START_OBJECT)**

O que a mensagem acima nos mostra é que o valor obtido com a chamada começa com `{`, ao invés de um `[`, que seria o correto no caso de uma chamada que se espera retornar uma lista.

Como o valor da resposta é um objeto JSON e não uma lista, o Jackson não consegue deserializar essa informação em um `List<Travel>`, e isso gera a exceção.

Algo que pode explicar este problema é se a chamada está obtendo um erro HTTP de qualquer natureza, o qual o corpo da resposta é um objeto JSON, e não uma lista. Uma vez que o `TestRestTemplate` por padrão não lança exceções em caso de erros HTTP, este pode estar tentando utilizar o Jackson para deserealizar a resposta do erro, que é um objeto, em uma lista, gerando a exceção acima. Isto explicaria porque no cURL, no Httpie e no RestTemplate, sua request funciona sem problemas: Os dois primeiros não precisam deserializar a resposta num objeto Java e portanto não se "importam" com qualquer contrato, e o terceiro, em caso de erros, lançará um `HttpStatusCodeException` e não tentará fazer qualquer deserialização com o Jackson.

Comment: PS/off-topic: Se eu fosse apostar, diria que é um erro na autenticação.

Comment: Valeu, mano! Realmente, está retornando uma exceção HTTP. Eu retirei a autenticação para debugar, mas o problema ainda persiste.